# Force WSUS to rescan WSUSContent folder

Tags: wsus

I have a disconnected WSUS server. On my Internet-connected WSUS server, I performed an export. On the disconnected server, I performed an import, then copied the WSUSContent folder from the Internet-connected system to the disconnected system.

On the disconnected server, for the vast majority of updates, WSUS reports that "the files for this update have not yet been downloaded." When I click the file information, the files are present in the path listed.

I tried "wsusutil.exe reset", but that didn't fix the issue. It seems like the database simply won't check the file structure and see that the files are already there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you also export the metadata with `wsusutil.exe export meta.cab logfile.txt` and then import it with `wsusutil.exe import meta.cab logfile.txt` or did you just copied the files?

Comment: I performed the export and import as you described. However, I performed the import command *before* copying the WSUSContent folder. I think that might have caused the problem. I'm now performing a new import with WSUSContent folder contents in place.

Comment: @MichaelCornn Did re-importing the metadata solve your problem? One of the ways I've solved this in the past is by using a 'sacrificial' WSUS. It'll have the metadata and content but say "the update is downloading". A second 'real' WSUS will synchronize to the sacrificial WSUS and successfully register the content. Not elegant but it works.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't fix it. Import is just extremely flaky.

Comment: I wrote a Powershell script using the get-wsusserver command. In the properties of the object it returned, I found the path to each file required. The script lists how many approved updates are missing files, and what the files are.

Comment: With a slight change to the script, I also found which updates *do* have all their corresponding files. I'm currently dissecting the SUSDB database to find where the files' download status is located. If I can find that, I'm going to manually update the rows for downloaded files and see if WSUS then recognizes the files.

Comment: I did not have luck with the reimport of the metadata either. I did find the dbo.tbFileOnServer table in the SUSDB with "DesiredState" and "ActualState" values but the rows with values greater than 1 don't seem to correspond with the updates looking for files. Not sure where to go from there.